# Apple AppStore not showing app after ready for sale status

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, non-renewing-subscription

Its been more then 12 hours that we have manually released the app from pending developer release to ready for sale & still its not showing up on appstore.

When I have checked my developer account portal I got error as follows and I doubt because of following error my app is not showing on appstore:

> "Add a credit/debit card to maintain membership benefits and keep your
>   apps available on the App Store."

[image]

Is it because we have removed the debit/credit information from developer account while we have enabled auto renewal option?

We have still 5 months left to expire the current subscription.

Please do let me know if this is the issue which preventing my app from now showing up on the app-store.

Comment: Give it some time, sometimes it happens :)

Comment: try to use the app's appstore url to find the app... if it's showing there then it's probably ok cause it takes time to come up in appstore search

Comment: @ArnabHore we have tried with iTunes connect's View on App Store url. even with the browser we have tried but no success

Answer (score 1):

You might have enabled auto-renewal option & didn't saved the card information. But its nothing related App publish process if there is an error apple will mail on admin + developer emails(if added).

Comment: but the status of app is ready for sale!!!and in the above image they said keep your app available  on the appstore . so I might doubt that it is only because of this my app is not showing on appstore.